# Chrome extension: How to load an external site in background insert script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good morning,
I have create a script with the extension CJS( custom javascript for website) for chrome that click and inject script on several page of a same domain automaticly, the script detect when the page change and alert me(with a simple alert()) about a new content in the page.

It works perfectly but I need to let open the web page, I put it as homepage but I don't wanna inadvertently close it. So I have create an extension with an iframe that contain the site witch I want insert the script but the extension CJS does not works on chrome extension.
The problem is that the site is in https so event if I disabled the Content Security Policy (CSP) I can't get the content of the iframe and inject script myself.

So my question is how to have a background page of an external site that let me execute script with chrome.
The extension is for personal use, I don't need an universal solution.

Thanks

edit:
the iframe appear in the default_popup: [image]

Comment: This info isn't sufficient to answer the question. It's not clear where that iframe is, which script should be injected, what exactly that CJS does and why you're using it instead of doing whatever you want in your extension.

Comment: I edit the post to show where is the Iframe, it is in the default_popup of the extension. What I want to do in my extension is click on some link on an external website to reconnect me when I am disconnect and reload an page and compare if it change or not. I can't just do ajax request because they are complexe javascript and interaction with different frame on the website and the website is not mine.

Comment: Hmm. When extension's popup is closed its document is completely destroyed, and recreated on next open, so it doesn't serve your purpose of keeping it from inadvertent closing. It's still not clear how you want to inject the script and what error is shown (rightclick the popup and then `Inspect` to show its console).

Comment: Yes you're right, the document is destroyed. The error is "refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-zByRuCdvjl9Usa83cvUrakS219KYS73bkGByf5Dj7ZA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution." so I add  in manifest this "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-zByRuCdvjl9Usa83cvUrakS219KYS73bkGByf5Dj7ZA",
but it change nothing

Comment: if the document is destroyed I have to find an other solution that default-popup maybe I can open a real popup out of the screen.